# Is the following inequality true or not?

Tags: inequality, triangles

$\left\|\sum_{m=1}^{M}\left(x_{m}^{t+1}-x_{m}^{t}\right)\right\|^{2}$
$\leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}\left\|x_{m}^{t+1}-x_{m}^{t}\right\|^{2}$, where $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ denote the 2-norm, and the $x_{m}^{t}$ is the vector.

Comment: This is the triangle inequality.

Comment: Are the double verticals supposed to be absolute value or a norm?

Comment: @Milten Double verticals are the standard notation for a norm.

Comment: The in equality is false. Consider one dimensional vectors and expand the square on the left to see it is false.

Comment: This should apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. I found the proof below.

Comment: Proof for what? Not for the original inequality because the original inequality is false.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is false for the same reason that $(1+2)^{2} \leq 1^{2}+2^{2}$ is false.

Comment: Thanks. I found the proof.

Comment: No, you didn't find a proof for  the inequality in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} y_{i}\right)^{2} \leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}^{2}\right)$$

The left hand of our inequality can be represented as follows.

$
\left\|\sum_{m=1}^{M}\left(x_{m}^{t+1}-x_{m}^{t}\right)\right\|^{2} = \left\|\sum_{m=1}^{M}\left(x_{m}^{t+1}-x_{m}^{t}\right)\times 1\right\|^{2} \\ \leq \sum_{m=1}^{M}\left\|x_{m}^{t+1}-x_{m}^{t}\right\|^{2} \times \sum_{m=1}^{M}1^2= M\sum_{m=1}^{M}\left\|x_{m}^{t+1}-x_{m}^{t}\right\|^{2}
$

Therefore, the origin inequality lacks M.